# Mediaquerys in a shopsystem

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

Im using a shopsystem called "Prestashop" it is basicly free but supports a bunch of modules. I purchased a module ages ago that manages the backgrounds on the website with javascript or css3.

I also can add .css elements so i edited it like this:

```
.nav .container { background: #333; }
.container {background: #f6f6f6;}
.functional-buttons {display:none!important}
@media (min-width: 1900px!important)
```

everything is working except the last one. The idea is to just display the modules background if the screen resolution is 1900px or higher. Im pretty sure i failed it somehow but i hope you guys can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 1900px!important) {
.nav .container { background: #333; }
.container {background: #f6f6f6;}
.functional-buttons {display:none!important}
}
```

is that it?

Comment: It's best if you explain how this code helps answer the OP's question, rather than just paste random code blocks.

Comment: Okay, i found that the background of my page got the class "vegas-background" so if i want to disable the background if the resolution is lower than 1900 it should look like this:

    `@media (min-width: 1900px) {
      .vegas-background {display:none}
    }`

or am i wrong?

Comment: It's almost that.
You want the css to be read when the condition in the media query is right. So you want max-width: 1900px
With min-width, it will apply as soon as you go over 1900px

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it? I tryed it that way: `@media (min-width: 1900px)and(max-width: 2100px) {  
  #vegas-background{
    display:none;
  }     
}` but this isnt working for me.